# KVM Guest using Physical SATA disk

Tags: ubuntu, storage, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

Is there a way to get my Ubuntu server (running as a guest in KVM) to use one of the hosts SATA disks? I Want it to have exclusive access and I believe there should be a "native" way. I have googled this for some time but found nothing.

Sorry if there are spelling errors, not my native tongue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using virt-manager to mange your KVM instances, you can just open it, click on your instance, go to View → Details. There is a button "Add Hardware" were you can add Storage, which may also be a whole hard disk drive. Use 'VirtIO' as a means to access the hard drive - this works well with recent linux kernels, if your guest operating system is linux.

Beware that you **do not use the hard disk on the hypervisor** as long as the instance is running. E.g. if you mount a filesystem on the hypervisor that resides on the disk and is mounted from within the virtual machine, you are probably going to destroy the filesystem. So, a little extra caution pays well ;-)

Comment: I wonder if the guest OS why I get a permission denied when I try to launch a windows XP guest.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in virt-manager, is to add the disk as a storage pool.
To do that, rightclick the localhost(QEMU) connection, select "details", "storage" tab, click the "plus" button and follow the wizard to add a new storage pool based on the physical disk (you get a choice there, can actually break the disk into parts with LVM)
Then create a volume on that disk, and when you create a VM, attach the pre-created volume